# copy list of filenames in a textfile in bash

Tags: bash

I need to copy a list of filenames in a textfile. Trying by this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mjdstart=55133
mjdend=56674
datadir=/nfs/m/ir1/ssc/evt
hz="h"

for mjd in $(seq $mjdstart $mjdend); do
    find $datadir/ssc"${hz}"_allcl_mjd"${mjd}".evt -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf $datadir'/%f\n' > ssc"${hz}".list
done
```

I tried also:

```
find $datadir/ssc"${hz}"_allcl_mjd"${mjd}".evt -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf $datadir'/%f\n' | split -l999 -d - ssc"${hz}".list
```

Or other combinations, but clearly I am missing something: the textfile is empty. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You re right: I have edited the message.

Comment: `find` here is overkill: you're running an external program simply to see if a single file exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `>>` (append) instead of `>` (overwrite) otherwise you will have output of last command only:

```
> ssc"${hz}".list
for mjd in $(seq $mjdstart $mjdend); do
    find $datadir/ssc"${hz}"_allcl_mjd"${mjd}".evt -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf $datadir'/%f\n' >> ssc"${hz}".list
done
```

Comment: What does the first line do?

Comment: First line just truncates the output file to 0 byte.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work` what error are you getting? Remove `>> ssc"${hz}".list` part and see what it prints.

Comment: Also echo the arguments to see, if `find` executes, what you think: `for...M; do echo ...; done`

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean that it doesn't write in the textfile the filenames. Sorry, what should I 'echo'?

Comment: As I suggested remove `>> ssc"${hz}".list` part and see if find commands actually give your desired output on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `find` here, as you simply have a range of specific file names whose existence you are checking for:

```
#!/bin/sh

mjdstart=55133
mjdend=56674
datadir=/nfs/m/ir1/ssc/evt
hz="h"

for mjd in $(seq $mjdstart $mjdend); do
    fnname="$datadir/ssc${hz}_allcl_mjd${mjd}.evt"
    [[ -f $fname ]] && printf "$fname\n"
done > "ssc$hz.list"
```

Comment: That's also a nice solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find` wrong. The first argument is the directory, in which it should search. Also, using `>` overwrites your list file in every turn. Use `>>` to concatenate:

```
find $datadir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "src${hz}_allcl_mjd${mjd}.evt" >> ssc"${hz}".list
```

Comment: do you mean, within the cycle, right?
How can I be sure that the script sees those files?